Chatbot integration using rasa
I have a frontend reactjs which gives the training model details like intend and actions in the json format , I need to convert them into them into rasa model format thorugh a python api. help me solve this problem
I have a json like this
{
  "rasa_nlu_data": {
    "common_examples": [
      {
        "text": "Hello",
        "intent": "greet",`your text`
        "entities": []
      },
      {
        "text": "Hi there!",
        "intent": "greet",
        "entities": []
      },
      {
        "text": "Good morning",
        "intent": "greet",
        "entities": []
      },
      {
        "text": "Hey, how are you?",
        "intent": "greet",
        "entities": []
      }
    ]
  }
}


try to convert them into the rasa yml files or modals
